# How to Add QnA Maker service to a chatbot which has LUIS

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have a chatbot that is already integrated with Luis. I am using .NetCore 2.0 with sdk v4.

I have created a knowledge base in QnA Maker. Now I am ready to add QnA Maker to my chatbot. I am kind a stuck at adding QnA Maker service in my bot.

This is my .bot file

```
{
  "name": "Bot",
  "description": "",
  "services": [
    {
      "type": "abs",
      "appId": "",
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Bot",
      "resourceGroup": "",
      "serviceName": "",
      "subscriptionId": "",
      "tenantId": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "connectionString": "",
      "id": "",
      "resourceGroup": "",
      "serviceName": "",
      "subscriptionId": "",
      "tenantId": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "luis",
      "appId": "",
      "authoringKey": "",
      "id": "5",
      "name": "BotwithAgent",
      "region": "westus",
      "version": "0.1"
    },
    {
      "type": "QnA",
      "KnowledgeBaseId": "",
      "EndpointKey": "",
      " Host": "",
      "id": "5",
      "name": "DevChatbotKB"
    },
    {
      "type": "endpoint",
      "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
      "name": "development",
      "id": "7"
    }
  ],
  "padlock": "",
  "version": "2.0",
  "path": "C:\\Users\\snaeem\\Desktop\\Work\\bot\\cafe-bot.bot",
  "overrides": null
}
```

And this is the part where the bot loads configurations:

[image]

I do not see my QnA Maker service being loaded. Is there any other way to load it?

Secondly, can someone guide me to a post/github repo that has luis+qna maker in .NetCore using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your `.bot` file:

- This method of providing settings to a bot has been deprecated in version 4.3 and above of the SDK as per [this documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1006#issue-431056357).
- The `type` for your QnA entry should be "qna" as per the source [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/637e26b0105c0b80654aee3a61f8caccd0636b69/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Configuration/ServiceTypes.cs#L21) and snapshot of the code for the `Startup` file before it was migrated to use an `appSettings.json` file is available [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/236bc24e40c25c2906dc14e1edef43266aded3e0/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch/Startup.cs).

The sample you are after for integrating LUIS and QnA Maker is [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) (nlp-with dispatch). There is a guide available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) which will step you through how it all works and getting it up and running.

Comment: I have started looking into Nlp with dispatch, thank you for sharing. Can i use this code as is? Like if i follow tutorial and create a dispatch file, the code is complete for the tutorial? barring all the ID and keys.

Comment: I am asking because tutorial states "protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync" class and the code does not have it

Comment: Yes you can use the code as-is by plugging in your keys. Sometimes the docs take a while to catch up to the latest version of the code, you can see that the docs were updated at the end of May but the code was updated a few days ago.

Comment: yes, I was working on the old code that is why I was wondering if it can be used as is or not..now i have the updated code.